# How can I intentionally create a simple runtime error?

Tags: java, testing, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm testing a batch script, to check that it's handling any errors when a compiled jar is run.

What's the simplest snippet of a code I can add to my java to cause a runtime error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply throw a [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html):

```
throw new RuntimeException("Test runtime exception");
```

Comment: How do I insert this without getting a `unreachable statement` compilation error?

Comment: The way I did it was by just replacing everything that was in the main block with your snippet. Works for what I'm doing.

Comment: put an `if (true)` statement before it

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
  int x = 10/i; // Arithmetic exception
}
```

Comment: Seems like a rather convoluted way to do something so simple.

Comment: Put `if(true)` instead of loop, if you like. Just some another way of doing wht OP wants :)

Comment: Ideally any such code is hardwaired and difficult to remove without recompiling later. Just for testing a jar file, I would pass an argument through cmd line and induce an exception conditionally while testing.

Answer (score -1):

declare `x` before for loop
then type `x=10/i;`